# ES6 export default with multiple functions referring to each other

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

in es6 there you can define a module of functions like this

```
export default {
    foo() { console.log('foo') }, 
    bar() { console.log('bar') },
    baz() { foo(); bar() }
}
```

the above seems to be valid code, but if I call `baz()` it throws an error:

`ReferenceError: foo is not defined`

How do you call `foo` from another function? in this case `baz`

**Edit**

Here's the code that actually doesn't work. I have simplified the code so it's only the core as needed

```
const tokenManager =  {
  revokeToken(headers) { 
    ... 
  },
  expireToken(headers) {
    ...
  },
  verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    jwt.verify(... => {
      if (err) {
        expireToken(req.headers)
      }
    })
  }
}

export default tokenManager
```

and the error is

```
expireToken(req.headers);
        ^
ReferenceError: expireToken is not defined
```

**Edit 2**

I just tried adding `tokenManager` before `expireToken` and it finally works

Comment: See my or @pawel's answer. To fix, replace `expireToken(req.headers)` with `tokenManager.expireToken(req.headers)` or with `this.expireToken(req.headers)`.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

The `export default {...}` construction is just a shortcut for something like this:

```js
const funcs = {
    foo() { console.log('foo') }, 
    bar() { console.log('bar') },
    baz() { foo(); bar() }
}

export default funcs
```

It must become obvious now that there are no `foo`, `bar` or `baz` functions in the module's scope. But there is an object named `funcs` (though in reality it has no name) that contains these functions as its properties and which will become the module's default export.

So, to fix your code, re-write it without using the shortcut and refer to `foo` and `bar` as properties of `funcs`:

```js
const funcs = {
    foo() { console.log('foo') }, 
    bar() { console.log('bar') },
    baz() { funcs.foo(); funcs.bar() } // here is the fix
}

export default funcs
```

Another option is to use `this` keyword to refer to `funcs` object without having to declare it explicitly, [as @pawel has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33179005/804678).

Yet another option (and the one which I generally prefer) is to declare these functions in the module scope. This allows to refer to them directly:

```js
function foo() { console.log('foo') }
function bar() { console.log('bar') }
function baz() { foo(); bar() }

export default {foo, bar, baz}
```

And if you want the convenience of default export *and* ability to import items individually, you can also export all functions individually:

```js
// util.js

export function foo() { console.log('foo') }
export function bar() { console.log('bar') }
export function baz() { foo(); bar() }

export default {foo, bar, baz}

// a.js, using default export

import util from './util'
util.foo()

// b.js, using named exports

import {bar} from './util'
bar()
```

Or, as @loganfsmyth suggested, you can do without default export and just use `import * as util from './util'` to get all named exports in one object.

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't make it work. I have edited the question with the real code. Can you see what goes wrong here?

Comment: @chrs, see my comment under your question. You need to replace `expireToken` with `tokenManager.expireToken`.

Comment: @chrs I was faster by a minute ;) But I don't mind, I like the last suggestion here (`export default { foo, bar, baz }`) and probably would use it myself.

Comment: "*if you want the convenience of default export and ability to import items individually*" - then you should not re-export an object literal as default, but simply write `import * as util from './util'`. That's precisely what namespace imports were made for.

Answer (score 31):

One alternative is to change up your module. Generally if you are exporting an object with a bunch of functions on it, it's easier to export a bunch of named functions, e.g.

```
export function foo() { console.log('foo') }, 
export function bar() { console.log('bar') },
export function baz() { foo(); bar() }
```

In this case you are export all of the functions with names, so you could do

```
import * as fns from './foo';
```

to get an object with properties for each function instead of the import you'd use for your first example:

```
import fns from './foo';
```

Comment: This definitively is the superior solution. Use named exports instead of default objects.

Answer (score 16):

tl;dr: `baz() { this.foo(); this.bar() }`

In ES2015 this construct:

```
var obj = {
    foo() { console.log('foo') }
}
```

is equal to this ES5 code:

```
var obj = {
    foo : function foo() { console.log('foo') }
}
```

`exports.default = {}` is like creating an object, your default export translates to ES5 code like this:

```
exports['default'] = {
    foo: function foo() {
        console.log('foo');
    },
    bar: function bar() {
        console.log('bar');
    },
    baz: function baz() {
        foo();bar();
    }
};
```

now it's kind of obvious (I hope) that `baz` tries to call `foo` and `bar` defined somewhere in the outer scope, which are undefined. But `this.foo` and `this.bar` will resolve to the keys defined in `exports['default']` object. So the default export referencing its own methods shold look like this:

```
export default {
    foo() { console.log('foo') }, 
    bar() { console.log('bar') },
    baz() { this.foo(); this.bar() }
}
```

See [babel repl transpiled code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=export%20default%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%28%29%20%7B%20console.log%28%27foo%27%29%20%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20bar%28%29%20%7B%20console.log%28%27bar%27%29%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20baz%28%29%20%7B%20this.foo%28%29%3B%20this.bar%28%29%20%7D%0A%7D).

Comment: When I do it like in your last example I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined` - what am I missing?