# Basic ES6 Javascript Plugin - reuse variable between functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to build a basic JS plugin that can be called after a click event to disable a button (to prevent users firing multiple API calls) and to give feedback that something is loading/happening. Here is how it looks:

[image]

This works great on an individual basis, but I want to re-write it as a plugin so I can reuse it across the site.

Here is a cut down version of the JS from file loader.plugin.js.

```
let originalBtnText;


export function showBtnLoader(btn, loadingText) {
  const clickedBtn = btn;
  const spinner = document.createElement('div');

  spinner.classList.add('spin-loader');

  originalBtnText = clickedBtn.textContent;
  clickedBtn.textContent = loadingText;
  clickedBtn.appendChild(spinner);
  clickedBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  clickedBtn.classList.add('loading');

  return this;
}


export function hideBtnLoader(btn) {
  const clickedBtn = btn.target;
  clickedBtn.textContent = originalBtnText;
  clickedBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  clickedBtn.classList.remove('loading');

  return this;
}


export function btnLoader() {
  showBtnLoader();
  hideBtnLoader();
}
```

And here is an example of how I would like to use it.

```
import btnLoader from 'loaderPlugin';

const signupBtn = document.getElementById('signup-btn');

signupBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  btnLoader.showBtnLoader(signupBtn, 'Validating');
  // Call API here
});

// Following API response
hideBtnLoader(signupBtn);
```

The issue I have is that I want to store the `originalBtnText` from the `showBtnLoader` function and then use that variable in the `hideBtnLoader` function. I could of course achieve this in a different way (such as adding the value as a data attribute and grabbing it later) but I wondered if there is a simple way.

Another issue I have is that I don't know the correct way of calling each individual function and whether I am importing it correctly. I have tried the following.

```
btnLoader.showBtnLoader(signupBtn, 'Validating');
btnLoader(showBtnLoader(signupBtn, 'Validating'));
showBtnLoader(signupBtn, 'Validating');
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showBtnLoader is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

I have read some good articles and SO answers such as http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html and [ES6 export default with multiple functions referring to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178843/es6-export-default-with-multiple-functions-referring-to-each-other) but I'm slightly confused as to the 'correct' way of doing this to make it reusable.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Import them in curly brackets from the target page { item , item } from './page'; and in the target page  export { item, item }

Comment: Plugin? Into what?

Comment: unless they're `export default` you must explicitly import them via `import { showBtnLoader } from 'loaderPlugin';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would export a function that creates an object with both show and hide functions, like this:

```
export default function(btn, loadingText) {

  function show() {
    const clickedBtn = btn;
    const spinner = document.createElement('div');

    spinner.classList.add('spin-loader');

    originalBtnText = clickedBtn.textContent;
    clickedBtn.textContent = loadingText;
    clickedBtn.appendChild(spinner);
    clickedBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    clickedBtn.classList.add('loading');
  }

  function hide() {
    const clickedBtn = btn.target;
    clickedBtn.textContent = originalBtnText;
    clickedBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    clickedBtn.classList.remove('loading');
  }

  return {
    show,
    hide,
  };
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
import btnLoader from 'btnloader';

const signupBtn = document.getElementById('signup-btn');
const signupLoader = btnLoader( signupBtn, 'Validating' );

signupBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  signupLoader.show();
  // Call API here
});

// Following API response
signupLoader.hide();
```

If you need to hide it from a different file from where you showed it, then you can export the instance:

```
export const signupLoader = btnLoader( signupBtn, 'Validating' );
```

And later import it.

```
import { signupLoader } from 'signupform';

function handleApi() {
    signupLoader.hide();
}
```

Comment: This really helped. Had to declare originalBtnText outside of the show and hide functions as it is used across both functions but other than that this worked well. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Youre maybe overriding the Element.prototype, to make it accessible right from that element. However, i wouldnt set values onto that element, i would rather return an object with all the neccessary stuff:

```
export function implementBtnLoader(){
 Element.prototype.showBtnLoader=function( loadingText) {
     const clickedBtn = this;
     const spinner = document.createElement('div');

     spinner.classList.add('spin-loader');

     var originalBtnText = clickedBtn.textContent;
     clickedBtn.textContent = loadingText;
     clickedBtn.appendChild(spinner);
     clickedBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
     clickedBtn.classList.add('loading');

    return {
        text:originalBtnText,
        el:this,
        hideBtnLoader: function() {
          const clickedBtn = this.target;
          clickedBtn.textContent = this.text;
          clickedBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
          clickedBtn.classList.remove('loading');
          return this;
       }
    };
  };
}


export function btnLoader() {
   implementBtnLoader();
}
```

When imported, and implementBtnLoader was called, one can do:

```
var loader=document.getElementById("test").showBtnLoader();
console.log(loader.text);
loader.hideBtnLoader();
```

Comment: I've just implemented your suggestions Jonas but I'm now getting 'Uncaught TypeError: clickedBtn.showBtnLoader is not a function at HTMLButtonElement'. I am importing the function using 'import btnLoader from 'loaderPlugin';' and trying to call the loader using 'clickedBtn.showBtnLoader('Loading');' (clickedBtn is the click target).

Comment: @GuerllillaRadio did youve executed the imported function? btnLoader();