# Vuejs - use function getProperties on exported class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have a source module:

```
import _ from 'underscore'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'

export default function (rxfb) {
  return {
    getProperties () {
      return rxfb.sources.user.getUser()
        .switchMap(({properties}) =>
          properties
            ? Observable.combineLatest(_(properties).map((property, propertyId) =>
              this.getProperty(propertyId).map(property => ({propertyId, ...property}))))
            : Observable.from([{}]))
    }
  }
}
```

I need to access it from another section so I am importing it:

```
import myProperties from '../../sources/properties'
```

Then I try:

```
console.log(myProperties.getProperties())
```

but it does not work, what is the proper way to get access to this method?

Comment: can u tell exactly what error you r getting

Comment: Getproperties is not a function

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178843/es6-export-default-with-multiple-functions-referring-to-each-other

Comment: I posted the answer let me know incase any issues are coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting a **`function`** BUT you are using it like an **`Object`**!

It seems that you have to use it like this (calling the function):

```
import myProperties from '../../sources/properties'
console.log(myProperties().getProperties())
```