# Import/Export several objects and functions under one name

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to combine the following:

```
// This is a React Component
import DataProvider from '../../../src/contexts/Data/DataProvider';
// This is a React Context
import DataContext from '../../../src/contexts/Data/DataContext';
// This is a function
import withDataContext from '../../../src/contexts/Data/withDataContext';
```

Into something like this:

```
import Context from 'context';
```

That allows all to be called as if they were imported individually:

```
withDataContext(something);
<DataProvider/>
```

etc.

I have read another answer here [ES6 export default with multiple functions referring to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178843/es6-export-default-with-multiple-functions-referring-to-each-other)

But this answer still results in the use of a object to hold all the exported functions.

i.e

```
Context.withDataContext(something)
```

Comment: No. To use individual variables, you have to import them individually.

Comment: you can put them in single file. and import them all with named export