# Problem import Typescript ES6 from export

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm converting my node code to typescript and running into a problem/confusion with regards to exporting and importing.

File: lookup.ts

```
const SecurityTypeSchema = new GraphQLObjectType({});
const EmailTypeSchema = new GraphQLObjectType({});
const PhoneTypeSchema = new GraphQLObjectType({});
const AddressTypeSchema = new GraphQLObjectType({});
const CountrySchema = new GraphQLObjectType({});

export default {
    SecurityTypeSchema,
    EmailTypeSchema,
    PhoneTypeSchema,
    AddressTypeSchema,
    CountrySchema
}
```

File: account.ts

Works:

```
import * as SecurityTypeSchema from './lookup';
import * as EmailTypeSchema from './lookup';
import * as PhoneTypeSchema from './lookup';
import * as CountrySchema from './lookup';
```

Error:

```
import {
    SecurityTypeSchema
    EmailTypeSchema,
    PhoneTypeSchema,
    CountrySchema
} from './lookup';
```

Error:

```
import * as Lookup from './lookup';
const {
    SecurityTypeSchema
    EmailTypeSchema,
    PhoneTypeSchema,
    CountrySchema
} = Lookup;
```

I like the last two options since I like grouping them.  I was looking at the following [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2440) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178843/es6-export-default-with-multiple-functions-referring-to-each-other) but I'm still getting an error.

If anyone can give me any tips I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt the one you labelled "Works" actually works. Did you even have a look at the objects?

Comment: You should [never default-export an object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43987935/1048572). Use `export const … = …;` and your second attempt at importing will work.

Comment: No I haven't I was just looking at the error vsc was giving me

Comment: Thanks for your link. It helps clarify what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Bergi Thanks for the link.  That helped a lot.  I see on VSC the objects now.